# 500 server error Laravel project after clone from github

Tags: linux, laravel, github

Im facing a problem with Laravel project after I clone it from Github repo.

At first there was an error with I type `php artisan serve` in a terminal and its return`PHP Warning:

> require(/home/peterwisu/github_workspace/test_git/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/peterwisu/github_workspace/test_git/artisan on line 18
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/peterwisu/github_workspace/test_git/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/peterwisu/github_workspace/test_git/artisan:18
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/peterwisu/github_workspace/test_git/artisan on line 18`

but I solve that by

```
composer install
```

it seem that every was fine I can run a command `php artisan serve`
but when I open a web pages its return  500 Server Error

So, I check a project in my mac laptop where I create a project It is working fine but when I clone it from github there is this error occurs in my linux pc.Plz help me out

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` then try again

Comment: Did you clone laravel/framework? You may follow https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-linux or mac or windows. I think cloning is not good idea

Answer (score 5):

When you are cloning a Laravel project from GitHub, you have to :

1. Run `composer install` on your cmd or terminal
2. Copy `.env.example` file to `.env` on the root folder
3. Open your `.env` file and change the database name (`DB_DATABASE`) to whatever you have, username (`DB_USERNAME`) and password (`DB_PASSWORD`) field correspond to your configuration
4. Run `php artisan key:generate`
5. Run `php artisan migrate`
6. Run `php artisan serve`
7. Go to http://localhost:8000/

and also run

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

to clone a larvel project :

1. git clone name_repository
2. Install the package with the composer install command
3. Then create an .env file filled with an existing file, namely .env.example
4. Then run the command php artisan key: generate
5. If there is a migration, the php artisan migrate command is needed
6. Lastly, run the Laravel program with php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

By default and for security the .env file is not cloned to your git repository.
I guess your project is missing the .env file and that is what is giving you the error 500.